# Alamofire does not work on Mobile after archive created swift 3 xcode 8

Tags: swift3, alamofire

I am using Alamofire 4.5 on XCode 8

When I am working on Simulator alamofire is working fine and when I connect my device to xcode via Cable then again its working fine.

When I create Archive of that particular build and run Diawi url link on my device to install the application it gets installed but alamofire start giving error

```
I am not able to get the root cause of the problem
```

I have tried couple of thing but nothing worked for me , Can anybody help me on this.
My Pod File

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
 use_frameworks!

target 'smartBrokerSuite' do
  # pod “CryptoSwift”
  pod ‘Google/Analytics’
pod ‘Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
pod 'CryptoSwift', :git => "https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift", :branch => “swift3”
pod 'Charts'
pod 'DKImagePickerController'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '5.0.0'

end

target 'smartBrokerSuiteTests' do

end

target 'smartBrokerSuiteUITests' do

end
```

Thanks in advance .!

Answer (score 1):

if the API method is GET then Do not put the http method in Alamofier.request() function

Alamofire.request(Url, parameters: args, encoding: URLEncoding.default)

```
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let JSON):
                successCallback((), JSON as AnyObject)

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try cleaning Cmd + Shift + Alt + K

this will work

Comment: I have installed using pod

Comment: what is difference between  command + shift +  and command +shift + alt + K  .. ?  I am trying this will let you know  @enea

Comment: Cmd + Shift + Alt + K it's just like cleaning derived datas. cleans everything , any data

Comment: Can you please let me know the difference .. ?

Comment: I have done the same and archiving the build , Will let you know

Comment: can i see your pod file please?

Comment: check my new answer

Answer (score 0):

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!


target 'smartBrokerSuite' do
  # pod “CryptoSwift”
  pod ‘Google/Analytics’
pod ‘Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
pod 'CryptoSwift', :git => 
"https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift", :branch => “swift3”
pod 'Charts'
pod 'DKImagePickerController'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '5.0.0'
end
```

Comment: Will try and will get back to you on ths.